# How can i convert ES6 template literal output to be a number?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was working on an algorithm and i want the output to be two space-separated long integers, but after getting the values and interpolating them as a template string literals, the values are always returned as strings.

I have tried return Number(`${minSum}`) Number(`${maxSum}`);
also, some Math methods, parseInt, and parseFloat, unary operator and * or maybe i am not doing it well.

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {  
let minSum = 0,  
maxSum = 0;    
for (let i = 1, j = 0; i < arr.length || j < arr.length - 1; i++, j++){  
minSum += arr[j];  
maxSum += arr[i];  
}  
return String.raw`${minSum} ${maxSum}`;  
}  
miniMaxSum([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]);
```

I expected the output to be 100 140, i keep getting "100 140";

Comment: Mathematically, 100 140 doesn't have a clear meaning - what is the mathematical interpretation for " "?

Comment: "space-separated" by definitions means string. Not sure what else you could be expecting. And yes, using template literals, especially with a `String.raw` tag, does create strings. Just don't use them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return multiple values. The closest you can do is to return an array containing 2 elements, like this:

```js
return [minSum, maxSum];
```

Comment: Or return an object and destructure it as needed :)

Comment: Thanks, it didn't quite work for me because i can only return one value from a function. The algorithm wasn't expecting me to return the value though but to console.log it. So I have solved by consoling the output, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

adding two number in string template can only string as string template always return a string. 
Now the question is how to return your values of `minSum` and `maxSum` from the function, you can return an array as @HeySora said in his answer, but I would suggest returning an object with two keys `minSum` and `maxSum`

```
return { minSum, maxSum, }
```

It can then be used as:

```
 const {minSum, maxSum } = miniMaxSum([1, 2, 3]);
 // minSum and maxSum can be used here
```

---

I am a little surprise seeing your question because sum will be the same be it 0 to end or reverse.

Comment: What is `value` and why would both properties have same `value`?

Comment: @charlietfl which value? ;)

Comment: @JonasWilms guess I need to stop drinking vodka at 8 in the morning!...poof...it's gone!